# Calculating a definite integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$
\int_{0}^{T}\frac{e^{-\alpha x}-e^{-\beta x}}{1-e^{-\gamma x}}dx
$$

Mathematica gives an answer based on the Hypergeometric Function. Could there be a closed form?

Comment: Already Mathematica gave you one!

Comment: The Mathematica command $$Integrate[(Exp[-a*x] - Exp[-b*x])/(1 - Exp[-c*x]), \{x, 0, T\},$$ $$Assumptions -> a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0 && T > 0] $$ produces $$(1/c)(-Beta[e^{c T}, 1 - a/c, 0] + Beta[e^{c T}, 1 - b/c, 0] - 
  HarmonicNumber[-(a/c)] + HarmonicNumber[-(b/c)]) .$$

Comment: Hypergeometrics are about all you can get here.